# Can a label only refer to input elements?

Tags: html, label, w3c

W3Schools have this to say about [labels](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp):

> The `<label>` tag defines a label for an **input** element.
> <sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Does this mean that the following HTML isn't valid?

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <title>Example document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label for="x">Label</label> 
            <hr>
            <div id="q" contentEditable="true">Hello</div>
            <hr>
            <div id="x" contentEditable="true">World</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Both Chrome and IE8 give focus to `World` when `Label` is clicked, Firefox does not.
Which is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) it applies to Form Controls, and Form Controls are [defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1):

- Buttons
- Checkboxes
- Radio buttons
- Menus
- Text input
- File select
- Hidden controls
- Object tags

So FireFox is technically right, although I'd hardly consider it to be "breaking" if a browser didn't restrict it to those elements.

Comment: If you want to label elements that are not controls, use [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)

Answer (score 5):

The HTML spec says, about `label`'s "for" attribute, "When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents."

So the id references in "for" should be that of a control.  What's a control?  The spec basically says any `input` is a control, as is `button`, `select`, or `object`.  So Firefox is technically right -- a `div` is not a control.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was not an appropriate use of the markup, because label semantics are that they are specifically for controls.

> The LABEL element is used to specify
>   labels for controls that do not have
>   implicit labels,

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 1):

The latest WhatWG spec has this to say:

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a label element.
>
> - `button`, `input` (if the `type` attribute is not in the Hidden state), `meter`, `output`, `progress`, `select`, `textarea`
>
> ...
>
> The `for` attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same tree as the `label` element.

(Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html.)

In other words, the standard only allows `for` attributes to point at elements of one of the 7 tag types listed above. The HTML exhibited in the question (which uses a `for` element to point to an editable `div`) is therefore technically invalid HTML under the current spec.

The [Nu Html Checker](https://checker.html5.org) (which is [endorsed by WhatWG](https://whatwg.org/validator/)) agrees; if you ask it to validate the HTML document from the question, it will say:

> **Error**: The value of the `for` attribute of the `label` element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.