# Label Tag semantics

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094352/can-a-label-only-refer-to-input-elements) and I GENERALLY use spans or strongs to describe "text-labels". Is this true for best practices? It seems  is also a semantic way but why is it limited to just form elements?

What if I wanted to display information as this:

```
Name: FOo Bar
Age: 27
Weight: 151 kg
```

etc?

name, age, and weight can all be described as labels, but since the items they're describing aren't input tags, it isn't semantically correct(for html and w3c at least). I usually use

```
<span class="label"> or <span class="description"> or <span class="person-detail"> etc
```

but generally there should also be a tag for labels that don't pertain to input fields. As this might be a bit subjective I don't mind this turning into a community wiki or something

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687733/what-html-markups-to-use-for-displaying-label-value-data

Answer (score 7):

You should use a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) (`dl` with `dt` and `dd`):

```
<dl>

 <dt>Name</dt>
 <dd>FOo Bar</dd>

 <dt>Age</dt>
 <dd>27</dd>

 <dt>Weight</dt>
 <dd>151 kg</dd>

</dl>
```

The spec states that it could be used for

> terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

---

I think a `table` (with `th`) *could* be used, too. But I would only use it when I want to compare *several* people, not just listing the data of one person.

Comment: This is incorrect. Having 151 kg as weight can't be part of a person's definition when it's subject to change by tomorrow. Age changes every year. All of those examples under the spec definition are permanent or strive to be permanent.

Comment: @DigitalNinja: That’s not true. Nothing in the HTML spec mandates (or even hints at) this. –– You mention examples. Note: 1) the examples are only informative, not normative. 2) There are examples with content which you might, under your interpretation, not consider to "strive to be permanent", e.g., "Last modified time" (which changes after each edit), and the price of a product (which can change often).

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid using a `label` tag unless it's in combination with a functional HTML form (with editable fields); otherwise, using it may be semantically confusing.

A `span` tag has no semantic meaning, regardless of the id or class added to it, and regardless of the context in which it's used. You don't gain anything semantically by using a `span` (though it does no harm).

A `strong` tag has a generic meaning (this content has extra importance) that doesn't vary based on the context in which it's used. It's sometimes useful when there's nothing else more appropriate.

In this particular case, a definition list (as suggested by @unor) seems like the way to go. If advanced styling is required, put each name-value pair into a separate definition list (which may be awkward semantically, but it allows greater flexibility with styling the content).

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you wanted to be 100% semantically correct you'd have to use labels in conjunction with disabled or readonly text boxes that have been styled to look a bit different.

Comment: i don't think disabled textboxes should even be used for display purposes only. only id there's a reason it should be disabled...right?

Comment: You could make it readonly. Might be a better idea to see how screen readers cope and use that as your standard.