# Semantic-respectful way to display a record in HTML5

Tags: html, record, semantic-markup

I'm stuck in deciding which tag I should use to display a single data record in a webpage in HTML5, i.e. user details such as id, username, creation date, modification date and so on:

```
ID:             1234
Username:       JohnnyBeGoode
Birth:          23/12/1962
Country:        Iceland
Created:        01/01/2009
Modified:       27/04/2010
```

The problem is I cannot find a proper tag, coherent with the semantic aspects of this view:

- **table**, **tr** and **td** tags are good for layout but semantically improper, since no tabular data is involved;
- **dl**, **dt** and **dd** are used by some frameworks, but I find them semantically quite far;
- list tags are not proper, since they're used with single values in each item, while I need to display a label and its related value;
- **label** tag is to be used only in forms, according to W3C Schools website.

Then, which coherent and meaningful tags should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear to me what you mean by "semantically quite far", but [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is the right element for this job:

> The `dl` element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list).
>
> […]
>
> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

There is even an example in the spec very similar to your case (comment starts with "The following example shows the `dl` element used to give a set of instructions.")

Example:

```
<dl>
  <dt>ID</dt>
    <dd>1234</dd>
  <dt>Username</dt>
    <dd>JohnnyBeGoode</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
    <dd>Iceland</dd>
</dl>
```

If you want to provide further information *about the content*, you should have a look at RDFa (e.g. [RDFa Lite 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/)) or Microdata. Looks to me like the vocabularies [FOAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF_%28software%29) and/or [SIOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantically-Interlinked_Online_Communities) could be used here.

Comment: I had no time to cite your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414974/label-tag-semantics?rq=1), which tells the same concept. Thanks again.